# Which way of locking access to a resource is the most pythonic/correct?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm building a multithreaded program because it has a ton of I/O. I want to build a queue that is continually populated with some partial information from a database, and replenish it when it gets low. All threads, at the end of a cycle, will check to see whether the queue needs replenishing. Which of these is the most accurate (mind you it's pseduo-code, since I'm only interested in the higher level concept).

Also, forgive me, I'm struggling a little bit with namespaces too, as you might see from the code. I've researched this heavily, tested heavily, and I'm still struggling, so any help is much appreciated!

```
# Option 1 - lock within the thread
class Thread():
    ...
    def run():
        # use an item off the queue
        with lock:
            replenish_queue()

lock = threading.Lock()
def replenish_queue():
    #check if queue needs replenishing

# ----------------------------------------

# Option 2 - lock within function
class Thread():
    ...
    def run():
        # use an item off the queue
        replenish_queue():

lock = threading.Lock()
def replenish_queue():
    with lock:
        #check if queue needs replenishing
```

Comment: Have you read about the GIL? Are you sure you need to implement locking?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The checking is done via sqlite calls to a database, and it's been struggling with very small levels of concurrency, so my guess is that I need to sync up database calls with locking, no?

Comment: Re: the *GIL*, if you haven't read about it, I highly recommend doing so. In short, due to the *GIL*, threading in *Python* can be...problematic... It's why often times multiple processes are used instead, where each one has its own GIL, and the issue is side-stepped.

Comment: Odd - usually the problem is emptying the queue, not filling it. Is there something external adding items to the database that is outside your control? Or some other reason you can't start with a queue of everything, or a queue that is added to by the same process that adds to the database?

Comment: @JohnMee Good question, so I'm just building a scraper to detect if a site has any pages with dead links. (So, not just dead links, but which pages actually have them.) It checks one page, and then "queues" the links from that page to go search them for dead links. I set this up with a queue, and my RAM blew out, (duh in retrospect). So now I "queue" them on disk in a database. Any idea how I could do this smarter?

Comment: I'm thinking generator: each thread asks a common routine, which is a generator, to provide the next item to process.  As a generator there should be no need to hold more than one, two, or five pages in memory at a time.  Only as many as it takes to eliminate page fetching delays.  No locks or synchronisation required.  Just a thought.

Comment: Are you trying to do a lot of concurrent reads to *sqlite*, writes, or both? From your post there's definitely a lot of reads, but do you need to write the output of your script back to the DB?

Comment: @khampson yes I update into the database throughout. And I'm trying to keep the reads/writes non-concurrent, but I think I'm failing since I get errors that the database is locked.

Comment: Why not Celery, which will handle concurrency itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a huge amount of concurrent database writes, I think one of your main bottlenecks is actually likely to be *sqlite* itself. Write locks happen in *sqlite* at the *database* level (http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html).

This is in contrast to other *RDBMS*'s, such as *Postgres*, which offer locking at the table level for updates, in conjunction with *MVCC*, which in terms of updates means that an `UPDATE` to a table, which will lock it for write, won't block other `SELECT`s from running.

So, whether you're accomplishing it through threading or multiple processes, trying to concurrently write to the same *sqlite* database is essentially a serial process, since *sqlite* requires a write lock be taken out on the entire DB for the duration of the write.

You can, however, have concurrent reads on an *sqlite* database. So if your usage pattern is such that you can do a bunch of reads, process them (from an internal queue or similar), and then do the writes serially (since *sqlite* essentially enforces a mutex on the database for writes anyway), that would probably be optimal.

In terms of the queue itself, a generator, as was mentioned by John Mee is definitely one option, and may be best depending on your exact data needs.

However, another worth considering is using the database itself as a queue -- SQL tables are generally good at that; I do it all the time in *Postgres*, and I suspect they work similarly well in *sqlite*. This would of course work best if your requirements are in one table, or could be consolidated easily into one queue. If your requirements include tons of disparate tables that aren't easily `JOIN`ed, or tables from different databases, then there would need to be an *ETL* layer in between to get it in to queue form, which may not be worth it at that point.

In the case it does fit well using the DB as a queue, using your *sqlite* library (say, `sqlite3`), you would declare your `cursor` and could either use it as an iterator to go over it one by one, or, `fetchmany` with a `size` parameter equivalent to the batch you want to process at once -- let's say 100.

You could then parcel that out to another process (i.e. using `multiprocessing`) to do the work while the main thread fetches the next chunk. It may worth it first, though, to have a single thread process each chunk -- tinker with the chunk size of the fetch to see if that helps, as often time it's the DB interaction where the real time is spent -- and see if the main thread can just whip through the chunks in an acceptable time on its own. If not, then you can always parcel it out to a bunch of workers and join them up afterwards.

When the cursor runs out of chunks to fetch, you're done the main read work, and forked processes (or the main process if you're going that route) are doing their processing throughout, and once those are all done you can then update them back in the main thread serially.

Multiple threads/processes are certainly sometimes needed, especially when doing a ton of I/O, but that's not always the case -- sometimes well planned/chunked database fetches can help a ton and obviate the need to add the extra complexity of multithreading/multiprocessing -- so I would recommend starting with that and building out from there only if actual observed performance dictates that.

**Edit:**

I see from one of the comments that you're already queueing using the database. If by this you mean what I was talking about above, then I think fetching in batches -- and tinkering to find the optimal size -- should help with performance (less roundtrips to the DB = less overhead, even with a local DB) -- and will definitely help with memory consumption since, if you have, say, 10 million items in the queue, you'll only fetch `size` items at a time.